# R plotly multiple lines plot facing issues with also multiple y axis

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the code shared below that is supposed to have three lines, of which the first two being referenced on the first Y-Axis, and the third line being referenced on the second y-axis on the right hand side of the plot.
However, something is going wrong.

```
df = data.frame(AS_OF=as.Date(c("2006-10-31", "2006-11-30", "2006-12-29", "2007-01-31", "2007-02-28", "2007-03-30")), 
                VALUE1=c(62.790, 63.890, 60.160, 70.425, 67.675, 71.175), 
                VALUE2=c(62.79000, 63.34000, 62.28000, 64.31625, 64.98800, 66.01917), 
                VALUE3=c(0.000,  1.100, -2.630,  7.635,  4.885,  8.385)
)

plt <- plot_ly()

plt <- plt %>% add_lines(data=df
                         , x = df[['AS_OF']]
                         , y = df[['VALUE1']]
                         , type='scatter'
                         , mode = 'lines+markers'
                         , name='VALUE1'
                         , inherit = F
)

plt <- plt %>% add_lines(data=df
                         , x = df[['AS_OF']]
                         , y = df[['VALUE2']]
                         , type='scatter'
                         , mode = 'lines+markers'
                         , name='VALUE2'
                         , inherit = F
)


plt <- plt %>% add_lines(data=df
                         , x = df[['AS_OF']]
                         , y = df[['VALUE3']]
                         , type='scatter'
                         , mode = 'lines+markers'
                         , inherit = F
                         , name='VALUE3'
                         , yaxis= 'y2'
)

plt <- plt %>% layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y"
                                    , side = "right"
                                    , title = 'second_y_axis'
)
) 
plt
```

Somehow, the line that should represent VALUE1 column is showed in the legend but not on the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. The trace isn't missing. It is just hidden, as it was taking the same course as one of the other traces. I cleaned up your code and changed your example data to make it visible:

```
library(plotly)

df = data.frame(
  AS_OF = as.Date(c("2006-10-31", "2006-11-30", "2006-12-29", "2007-01-31", "2007-02-28", "2007-03-30")),
  VALUE1 = c(62.790, 63.890, 60.160, 70.425, 67.675, 71.175),
  VALUE2 = c(62.79000, 63.34000, 62.28000, 64.31625, 64.98800, 66.01917),
  VALUE3 = c(0.000,  5.100,-4.630,  0.635,  4.885,  -2)
)

plt <- plot_ly(data = df, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers')

plt <- plt %>% add_lines(
  x = ~ AS_OF,
  y = ~ VALUE1,
  name = 'VALUE1'
)

plt <- plt %>% add_lines(
  x = ~ AS_OF,
  y = ~ VALUE2,
  name = 'VALUE2'
)

plt <- plt %>% add_lines(
  x = ~ AS_OF,
  y = ~ VALUE3,
  name = 'VALUE3',
  yaxis = 'y2'
)

plt <- plt %>% layout(yaxis2 = list(
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  title = 'second_y_axis'
))

plt
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I literally copied and pasted your solution and still does not show the VALUE1 line. My plotly library has version ‘4.9.0’. Am I missing something?

Comment: I used the latest CRAN release v4.9.3. Maybe an update helps?

Comment: I'm currently kind of stuck with that version since I have to work with the libraries available on a server and it could take weeks before such libraries would get the approval to be updated unfortunately. Do you think the issue I face is a bug of the older version?

Comment: No, I don't think so. This is pretty basic plotly code.